# ZipArchive::filename, how is it supposed to work?

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I thought `ZipArchive::filename` would represent the path to the actual zip file, but for every zip file I open with `ZipArchive::open()`, `ZipArchive::filename` gives me an empty string.

Example:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open( '/some/path/to/zipfile.zip' );
var_dump( $zip->filename );

// expecting:
string(25) "/some/path/to/zipfile.zip"

// but getting:
string(0) ""
```

Am I misunderstanding `ZipArchive::filename`, or using it incorrectly perhaps?

Using PHP 5.2.6 on Apache, Windows XP here.

Comment: do you want to open the zip and extract the contents?

Comment: @Michael: I will be extending `ZipArchive` to represent backup files for which I will only be accepting filenames consisting of numbers (representing a date). I will be extracting files out of and archiving files into the archives. And I want to utilize `ZipArchive::filename` to give me the basename of the file.

Comment: it is working fine for me with php5.3.1 on win. can you var_dump() the return of the ::open() to see if there is some error? [error codes](http://ar.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-open.php#87423)

Comment: @Einacio: I'll try out `php > 5.3` myself someday too. Thanks for affirming this. Unfortunately production server will be `5.2` as well. `::open()` simply returns `true` as expected, `var_dump()` returns `object(ZipArchive)#1 (5) { ["status"]=> int(0) ["statusSys"]=> int(0) ["numFiles"]=> int(1450) ["filename"]=> string(0) "" ["comment"]=> string(0) "" }`. So at least `numFiles` actually works as expected (although I'm able to overwrite it, lol).

Comment: "(although I'm able to overwrite it, lol)" is not true actually. My bad.

Comment: perhaps it is a problem for your version. can't you update your 5.2 to 5.2.14 o some other revision? also, can't you use the filename string used to open the file as basename?

Comment: in the changelog for 5.2.9 "Fixed zip filename property read."

Comment: @Einacio: Yeah I think your last suggestion is what I'll end up doing, if the production server (shared host, so no control) fails as well. I was just curious why `filename` wasn't working as expected for my setup. Thanks for thinking along with me.

Comment: @Einacio: Oh really?! Why didn't I think of reading the changelogs? Nice one! Thanks again for thinking along with me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the [changelog for 5.2.9](http://ar.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.2.9) "Fixed zip filename property read."

try updating your php version